# Dynamically Allocate Memory for String Array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm trying to store a list of every mount point on a Linux system in a string array with C. I'm focused on this piece of code.

```
int i = 0;
char **mountslist = malloc(1024 * sizeof(char *));

/*
 * Make sure that the number entries in the array are less than the allocated
 * 1024 in the absurd case that the system has that many mount points.
 */
while (i < 1024 && (ent = getmntent(mounts))) {
    /*
     * The output of getmntent(mounts) goes down to
     * the next mount point every time it is called.
     */
    mountslist[i] = strdup(ent->mnt_dir);
    i++;
}
```

I was wondering how I could dynamically allocate the number of entries in the `mountslist` array (currently statically set at 1024) to avoid that limit and wasting memory. If I had the final value of `i` when declaring `mountslist` I could use `char *mountslist[i];` or `char **mountslist = malloc(i * sizeof(char *));`

Comment: you can do your second thing - `malloc(i *...`. The first one is a non standard c extension (variable length array)

Comment: Look up `realloc`.

Comment: 4k (or 8k on 64-bit systems) ain't gonna break the bank. I'd say you've already wasted enough time here. But you should learn about `realloc` if you're going to code in C.

Comment: @rici I agree that what I have here is probably pointless and the code I have now is fine, I just posted it as I couldn't find an answer so that now there will be one for other people in a similar situation.

Comment: It's only 1024 times sizeof(char *). You could simply realloc (downwards) afterwards.

Comment: depending on your further usage, you could be better off using a linked list instead fo the array. This way you can allocate as many entries as you really need.

Comment: Is 1024 an upper bound?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `realloc` to change the size of an allocated memory block:

```
int i = 0;
int len = 10;
char **mountslist = malloc(len * sizeof(char *));

while ((ent = getmntent(mounts)) != NULL) {
    if (i >= len) {
        len *= 2;
        char **tmp = realloc(mountslist, len * sizeof(char *));
        if (tmp) {
            mountslist = tmp;
        }
    }
    mountslist[i] = strdup(ent->mnt_dir);
    i++;
}
```

As shown above, a good rule is to double the amount of space you allocate when you run out of space.  That prevents excessive calls to `realloc` which may move the allocated memory each time.